# List Mailbox Permissions from CSV file

Tags: powershell, shell, format, exchange-server, user-permissions

I am making a list of Mailbox and their Permissions. so I have this small script that I made:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Path C:\Outlookcache_2019.csv -Delimiter ";"

foreach ($User in $Users)  {


                $Permissions = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity 
                $User.UserPrincipalName | select Identity,AccessRights

                $Output = New-Object psobject -Property @{

                           UserPrincipalName = $User.UserprincipalName
                           Identity = $Permissions.Identity
                           AccessRights = $Permissions.accessrights

               }

 
          $Output | Export-Csv -Path C:\Mail_Permissions.csv -Encoding 
          UTF8 -NoTypeInformaiton
 }
```

I need in the List the UserPrincipalName form the CSV because I need to merg the results with another EXCEL List. The Problem is when I have entries that have more then one User in the Permission Like for example:
Identity               AccessRights
John                   Read,write
Jane                   Read

this script format them as {John, Jane} {Read, Write, Read} as in it adds them together. How do I format this to get the Identity in the first entry to be in one line and the second in another line. so that I have them Later in an Excel File in one cell with two lines.
Thanx in Advance

I have not tried Regex is it possible with it to format it this way. I am new to Powershell

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand right, you want each record in your output to represent a delegate that has access to the mailboxes in your CSV?

You could do something like this:

```
$Mailboxes = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Outlookcache_2019.csv" -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)  {
    $Delegates = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName

    foreach ($Delegate in $Delegates) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserPrincipalName = $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName
            Delegate = $Delegate.User
            AccessRights = $Delegate.AccessRights
        } | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Mail_Permissions.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
}
```

Keep in mind though, this will only obtain delegates with "Read and Manage" access. Here is something more thorough that also shows who has "Send As" access.

```
$Mailboxes = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Outlookcache_2019.csv" -Delimiter ';'

foreach ($Mailbox in $Mailboxes)  {
    $DelegatesWithReadAndManage = Get-MailboxPermission -Identity $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName | Where-Object {$_.User -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"}
    $DelegatesWithSendAs = Get-RecipientPermission -Identity $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName | Where-Object {$_.Trustee -ne "NT AUTHORITY\SELF"}

    $Output = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[PSObject]
    foreach ($Delegate in $DelegatesWithReadAndManage) {
        $Record = [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserPrincipalName = $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName
            Delegate = $Delegate.User
            ReadAndManage = "TRUE"
            SendAs = "FALSE"
        }
        $Output.Add($Record)
    }

    :delegatesLoop foreach ($Delegate in $DelegatesWithSendAs) {
        foreach ($Record in $Output) {
            if ($Delegate.Trustee -eq $Record.Delegate)
            {
                $Record.SendAs = "TRUE"
                continue delegatesLoop
            }
        }

        $Record = [PSCustomObject]@{
            UserPrincipalName = $Mailbox.UserPrincipalName
            Delegate = $Delegate.Trustee
            ReadAndManage = "FALSE"
            SendAs = "TRUE"
        }
        $Output.Add($Record)
    }
    $Output | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Mail_Permissions.csv" -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Looking at that algorithm though, I'm realizing it would be faster if you stored your $Output into a hash table instead of a list. Since we are checking the full list of delegates with "Read and Manage" for every delegate with "SendAs" to see if they should be combined on the same record. If your data is going to scale greatly, see if you can come up with a better algorithm.

If you want to see who has "Send on Behalf" access too, that will add to the complexity even more, but hopefully this helps to get you in the right direction.